# Can browser Content Decryption Module (CDM) version be detected using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, firefox-addon

I want to get the version of CDMs supported by browsers. They are added as components/addons and each browser has a way to check these:

**Chrome - chrome://components/**

[image: Chrome components CDM]

**Firefox - about:addons**

[image: Firefox addons CDM]

Is there a way these can be detected using javascript in a normal tab?